# How to initialize spring configurations outside of JUnit?

Tags: java, spring, junit, configuration, javabeans

I have code that can be run properly as a JUnit test case. However, when I put the same test code inside a main class, spring configuration do not properly load the objects.

Spring code looks like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/fileonly-sens-services.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AppTest extends ContextBuilder {


    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        System.setProperty("app-
init.properties","classpath:test.app.properties");

@Test
someTestMethod()


}
```

I think it is a very simple problem but I cannot get it working outside of JUnit! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application you will have to create an ApplicationContext. The specifics of how to do it, depends on what kind of application you are building.

If you are building a command-line application, you can instantiate ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and use it to instantiate needed beans.

If you are building a web application, you can use ContextLoaderListener to load context during your application initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will give it a try. I tried googling but am a bit confused: what is the difference between @ContextConfigurations = "classpath:...xml" vs System.setProperty(app-init.properties, ...)?